# Android app crashing while parsing JSON

Tags: android, json, crash

I am parsing a String to JSON like this

```
try {
 x = new JSONObject(y);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

It's working fine for me, but I am getting a very rare crash on fabric,

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{a.b.c/a.b.XActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
   Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
   at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
   at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java)
   at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java)
   at com.razorpay.XActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:1454)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

This crash is not very rare and I am not able to reproduce it, but I am not able to understand, How can this happen when the code is already inside the 
try catch.

Comment: `Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException`. Because `y==null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that could be null and cause a NullPointerException (assuming that it is actually coming from this code) is your `y` variable. In addition, catching all possible `Throwable` objects can't hurt.

So perhaps this can help:

```
try {
    if (y != null) {
         x = new JSONObject(y);
    }
} catch (Throwable t) {
}
```